# Minimum/Maximum of $\mid x \mid $

Tags: calculus

In general when searching for minimum and maximum of a function on a closed interval, I am using fermat theorem $(f'(x)=0)$ and  the extreme value theorem.

But in the case of $\mid x \mid$ how should I approach this? should I also look for points the that are not differentiable?

Comment: Split the search into $(\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$. $|\cdot|$ is differentiable on each of these closed intervals.

Comment: You can also use the fact that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\vert x\vert=\dfrac{x}{\vert x\vert}$.

Comment: I gave $\mid x \mid$ as an example, in general, when looking for maximum and minimum points, one should also look at the point where is function is not integrable? or not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local extrema (maxima or minima) of a continuous function $f$ *can* exist at a point $a$ iff either:

- $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a) = 0$, or
- $f$ is not differentiable at $a$

So in the case of $f(x) = |x|$, $f$ can have a minima at $x=0$ since $f$ is not differentiable there.